# Make gallery suitable for phone view (small screen)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created an image gallery in HTML/CSS/JS however when I minimize the screen the image change doesn't appear it just opens up the image in a new window.

***Large Screen when the image is pressed:***
[image]

**Small Screen when the image is pressed:**
[image]

How can I keep it like that but just minimize it for smaller screens?

Here is the project:https://codepen.io/mican/pen/awxmpY?q=magnific&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false

HTML:

```
<article class='gallery'>
  <a class='gallery-link' href='https://unsplash.it/1600/1200?image=1081'>
    <figure class='gallery-image'>
      <img height='1200' src='https://unsplash.it/1600/1200?image=1081' width='1600'>
      <figcaption>Photo caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
  <a class='gallery-link' href='https://unsplash.it/1600/1600?image=1014'>
    <figure class='gallery-image'>
      <img height='1600' src='https://unsplash.it/1600/1600?image=1014' width='1600'>
      <figcaption>Photo caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
  <a class='gallery-link' href='https://unsplash.it/1200/1000?image=267'>
    <figure class='gallery-image'>
      <img height='1000' src='https://unsplash.it/1200/1000?image=267' width='1200'>
      <figcaption>Photo caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
  <a class='gallery-link' href='https://unsplash.it/1200/1600?image=266'>
    <figure class='gallery-image'>
      <img height='1600' src='https://unsplash.it/1200/1600?image=266' width='1200'>
      <figcaption>Photo caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
  <a class='gallery-link' href='https://unsplash.it/1000/1400?image=634'>
    <figure class='gallery-image'>
      <img height='1400' src='https://unsplash.it/1000/1400?image=634' width='1000'>
      <figcaption>Photo caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
  <a class='gallery-link' href='https://unsplash.it/1200/1200?image=923'>
    <figure class='gallery-image'>
      <img height='1200' src='https://unsplash.it/1200/1200?image=923' width='1200'>
      <figcaption>Photo caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
  <a class='gallery-link' href='https://unsplash.it/1400/1000?image=682'>
    <figure class='gallery-image'>
      <img height='1000' src='https://unsplash.it/1400/1000?image=682' width='1400'>
      <figcaption>Photo caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
  <a class='gallery-link' href='https://unsplash.it/1000/1400?image=173'>
    <figure class='gallery-image'>
      <img height='1400' src='https://unsplash.it/1000/1400?image=173' width='1000'>
      <figcaption>Photo caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
  <a class='gallery-link' href='https://unsplash.it/1200/1000?image=943'>
    <figure class='gallery-image'>
      <img height='1000' src='https://unsplash.it/1200/1000?image=943' width='1200'>
      <figcaption>Photo caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
</article>
<footer id='footer' role='contentinfo'>
  <div class='container'>
    <a class='logo' href='https://codepen.io/collection/XRoxGR' rel='home'>Calibration theme</a>
    <a class='copy' href='https://mobilemarkup.com'>&copy; mobileMarkup.com</a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

***basically when the image is pressed in a smaller screen it opens a new page in a smaller screen but I want it to open the gallery just like the larger screen***

Comment: what do you mean exactly about minimize it?

Comment: as in smaller screens or when you minimise the page

Comment: you want to change size of photo after it has been opened in new window? (i.e. width:100%)?

Comment: basically when the image is pressed in a smaller screen it opens a new page in a smaller screen  but I want it to open the gallery just like the larger screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove this code, and mobile like the larger screen

```
disableOn: ->
    return false if $(window).width() < 640
    return true
```